# node-schedule undoing cancellation

Tags: node.js, schedule, cancellation

I've been working with node for the first time in a while again and stumbled upon [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), which for the most part has been a breeze, however, I've found resuming a scheduled task after canceling it via job.cancel() pretty difficult.

For the record, I'm using schedule to perform specific actions at a specific date (non-recurring) and under some circumstances cancel the task at a specific date but would later like to resume it.

I tried using job.cancel(true) after cancelling it via plain job.cancel() first as the documentation states that that would reschedule the task, but this has not worked for me. Using job.reschedule() after having cancelled job first yields the same result.

I could probably come up with an unelegant solution, but I thought I'd ask if anyone knows of an elegant one first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to understand [node-schedule documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) ^^

To un-cancel a job, You have to give to `reschedule` some options.

If you don't pass anything to `reschedule`, this function returns false (Error occured)

For exemple, you can declare options, and pass this variable like this :

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

let options = {rule: '*/1 * * * * *'}; // Declare schedule rules

let job = schedule.scheduleJob(options, () => {
    console.log('Job processing !');
});

job.cancel(); // Cancel Job

job.reschedule(options); // Reschedule Job
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, while this isn't exactly the functionality I would have hoped for it helped me a lot since I somehow missed that you have to actually pass reschedule an argument. I was hoping I could just pass it nothing and it would simply undo the cancellation and perform the task at the time it was set to in the first place, however just passing in the same date as the option again works fine for my application.